# How to copy file from one folder to another in C#?

Tags: c#

I have a back up folder and a main folder in my project. I am giving an option to user in main menu to open file from backup folder. For that i have written code:

```
        string[] paths;
        string fullpath = "";
        paths = Directory.GetFiles(backuppath);
        foreach (string backupfilepath in paths)
        {
            if (path.EndsWith(".txt"))
                fullbackupfilepath = backupfilepath;
        }
```

Here backuppath is the path of the backup file.
Now i copy this back up file in main project folder:

```
         File.Copy(fullbackupfilepath, mainprojectfilepath);
```

But i get the error that Could not find file C:\Users\me\Desktop\csharpproject\bin\debug\BackupProject.txt

Why is it going in bin debug folder when my project is in MyDocuments\Myproject. There is backupfolder inside this Myproject folder.
Please help with a solution.

Comment: What is the contents of paths? Please make the question more clear.

Comment: shouldn't you avoid writing files to your bin directory?

Comment: @Frode:The content of the path is say .txt file.

Comment: @David: I am not writing files to bin, it is getting added on its own.

Comment: @sas Well, it sounds like that's exactly what you are doing. You appear to be copying it to the same folder as your executable which is generally considered a bad thing: see DanielB's answer.

Comment: I am already saving the files in My documents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use relative path rather than absolute path, in runtime the base folder is the folder where the executable is located. In debug mode it's bin/debug.

It's not advisable to have user files in the programs directory at all. I.e. if you install your program in Windows Vista or 7 programms folder, you will need admin rights to write into this directory.

You should have a look at `Environment.SpecialFolder`.

```
string yourAppPath = Path.Combine(
       Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData),
       "YourApp");
```

This piece of code will generate a path for the current user, where you could store the files.

Comment: You posted your project is within `MyDocuments\Myproject` that's not the same. On the other hand the application is looking into a desktops sub folder `C:\Users\me\Desktop\csharpproject\bin\debug\BackupProject.txt`. You should have a breakpoint on `File.Copy()` and see what the actual values of `fullbackupfilepath, mainprojectfilepath` are.

Comment: fullbackupfilepath shows MyDocuments\Myproject\Backup\BackupProject.txt and mainprojectfilepath shows MyDocuments\Myproject\project.txt

Comment: These are relative paths. You should use absolute paths starting with the drive letter.

Answer (score 0):

When you run your program from Visual Studio, it gets compiled into the `/bin/debug` subfolder of the project, and it gets run from there. That gets reflected in your paths inside your application as well.

You can add the file to your project just like your code files, and in it's properties select `Copy to output directory: Copy if newer' to make sure that the file is present in the`bin/debug` folder as well. Optionally you can copy the file in there manually if you do not want to make it part of your project.

Comment: How to rectify it? I will keep getting the error cause this backup file is not there in the debug folder. It is there in the main folder.

Comment: When you actually deploy this, they will be in the same folder, and all will be well. When under deployment, do as I suggested and add the backup file to the project, and set `Copy if newer` in it's properties. Then when the file gets changed, when if not from inside Visual Studio, it will get copied to the debug folder, and everything should be well.

Comment: This file when created in bin/debug folder cannot be accessed.

Answer (score 0):

In debug mode, a application directory is a same with executable file(.exe) directory. So the `backupfolder` is needed to add to bin folder, but it is valid only you and after publishing to some users, they cannot catch the `backupfolder`.

I think one of a solution is that the `backupfolder` with files you want to use is added to visual studio project and then set 'Do not copy' option of that files to 'Copys always'. It could be assured of a `backupfolder`'s path after publishing, if the `backupfolder` is included to deployment.

Comment: When i copy the folder then i am not able to access backup file.

Comment: Please, make sure that specific files you want to use are under 'bin\debug' folder after those file options are changed to 'Copys always' or 'Copy if newer', and are built. If sure, please understand the difference between relative path and absolute path. Good luck to you.