# Copying file from one directory to another with c#

Tags: c#

I have a directory path like this \servername\DirectoryName\.csv and in that there are multiple csv files of similar name pattern now I want to copy that from one directory to another in c#.Can anyone help me out with this.

Comment: outline what you've tried and ask the question again.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368799/how-to-copy-file-from-one-folder-to-another-in-c

Answer (score 3):

```
var sourceDir = @"c:\sourcedir";
var destDir = @"c:\targetdir";
var pattern = "*.csv";

foreach (var file in new DirectoryInfo(sourceDir).GetFiles(pattern))
{
   file.CopyTo(Path.Combine(destDir, file.Name));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Files.Copy() method. See msdn [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy.aspx).