# How do i copy files from one directory to another directory?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
string[] s = Directory.GetFiles(t, "*.txt",SearchOption.AllDirectories);
for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
{
    File.Copy(s[i],
}
```

File.Copy will copy the files to another file name.
I want to keep the same files names just copy them from one directory to another directory.

Comment: "File.Copy(s[i], "... Where is the rest of your code? This wouldn't compile.

Comment: Jordy i dont know what would be the rest. s[i] contain for example in index 0: c:\\temp\\test.txt now i want that test.txt will be copied to c:\\temp\\allmyfilescopiedhere

Comment: you dont define targert path

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this:

```
 File.Copy(s[i], "c:\\anotherFolder\\" + Path.GetFileName(s[i]));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it nicely like this:

```
Directory.GetFiles("c:\\temp", "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories) // get the files
    .Select(c => new FileInfo(c)) // project each filename into a fileinfo
    .ToList() // convert to list
    .ForEach(c => c.CopyTo("d:\\temp\\" + c.Name)); // foreach fileinfo, copy to the desired path + the actual file name
```

Answer (score 1):

You could view [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12912702/copying-file-from-one-directory-to-another-with-c-sharp) post, which should help;

Or [this MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9706cfs5.aspx) link:

Code snippet:

```
var sourceDir = @"c:\sourcedir";
var destDir = @"c:\targetdir";
var pattern = "*.txt";

foreach (var file in new DirectoryInfo(sourceDir).GetFiles(pattern))
{
   file.CopyTo(Path.Combine(destDir, file.Name));
}
```

Hope this helps?

Comment: on a different matter re [one of your suggested edits](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2678872): the apostrophe was misused, for plural only append an `s`, _with_ apostrophe "domain's something" would mean "the something of domain" - see http://theoatmeal.com/comics/apostrophe

Comment: @TobiasKienzler Very true, not sure how I missed that, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it the right way..

See example from microsoft

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762914.aspx

another solution might be to call the [xcopy](http://www.computerhope.com/xcopyhlp.htm) command ...

Comment: file copy. copy all files from one directory to another directory. not to copy the directory but the files inside.